# Nelson 0.4.0 crash

Tags: neighbors, nelson

I run a full node with the [Nelson](https://github.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli) tool, version 0.4.0, for neighbor management.

For a while now Nelson frequently crashes with the message:

```
Error: Invalid URL: ws://[iota.kun.com:14600]:NaN
```

This problem persists also with the newest (1.4.2.4) version of IRI and the URL in the error message doesn't belong to any of my configurations.

How can I fix that?